# What needs to be done to include a categorical and numerical covariate (eg gender and age)?

Tags: r, statistics, emmeans, ancova

I have the following code, and Gender is a dummy variable as M0, F1:

Example Data:

```
ID  Feature Age Gender  Category
1   96  30  0   category 1
2   57  42  0   category 1
3   82  37  0   category 1
4   87  43  1   category 1
5   8   47  1   category 1
6   52  35  0   category 1
7   29  36  0   category 1
8   48  34  1   category 1
9   13  25  0   category 1
10  53  39  1   category 2
11  64  44  0   category 2
12  70  33  0   category 2
13  31  27  1   category 2
14  88  27  1   category 2
15  37  53  0   category 2
16  6   29  0   category 2
17  44  60  0   category 2
18  71  54  1   category 2
19  78  54  0   category 2
20  64  48  0   category 3
21  68  57  1   category 3
22  31  36  1   category 3
23  18  34  0   category 3
24  42  53  0   category 3
25  1   38  0   category 3
26  47  54  0   category 3
27  18  22  0   category 3
28  65  28  0   category 3
29  23  45  1   category 3
30  46  45  0   category 3
```

My Ancova is defined as
Ancova

```
res.aov <- df_copy %>% anova_test(Feature ~ Age + Gender + Category)
```

Pairwise post hoc

```
pwc <- df_copy %>% 
  emmeans_test(
    formula = Feature ~ Category, 
    covar = Age,
    p.adjust.method = "bonferroni"
  )
```

This works fine with just Age, but adding gender alone or combined with age causes problems - what needs to be done to have two covariates in emmeans and what extra needs to be done for dummy variable Gender.

Comment: Could you share some sample data using something like `dput(df_copy(1:25,])`?

Comment: I can't share the data- but generating with random numbers it is in the form:         
id feature age gender
1 74 57 0
2 94 32 1
3 56 48 1
4 18 24 1
5 55 34 0
6 87 46 0
7 75 41 0
8 78 55 0
9 5 30 0
10 94 43 1
11 40 60 1
12 58 60 1
13 78 58 0
14 48 60 1
15 100 30 1
16 83 58 0
17 29 43 1
18 78 46 1
19 22 42 0
20 2 59 0
21 82 56 0
22 87 54 1
23 39 44 1
24 89 51 1
25 73 30 0
26 95 29 0
27 63 52 0
28 4 29 0
29 18 21 0
30 13 24 1

Comment: Could you edit your question to include this information? Please dont include it in the comments. Also please test and ensure the issue arises from the sample data

Comment: What does "causing problems" mean? Does it return an error, or provide results different than expected? Could you edit your question to specify? Also, we dont have `Category` in your sample data, so cant test it - as mentioned, when providing sample data please test it first to recreate the issue

Comment: Apologies edited and error still occurs on test data

Comment: Again, **what is "the error"**?

Comment: If code is updated to: pwc <- df_copy %>% 
+   emmeans_test(
+     Fasting_PYY ~ Category, covariate = Age + Gender,
+     p.adjust.method = "bonferroni"
+   )  - it gives message:  object 'Age' not found

Comment: Gender alone gives: Error in contrast.emmGrid(res.emmeans, by = grouping.vars, method = method,  : 
  Nonconforming number of contrast coefficients

Answer (score 0):

Are your variables coded as factors? To check if they are run `class(df$variable)`  to see what class of variable you have. If they are not factors they can be changed to factors by running:
`df$variable <- as.factor(df$variable)`

The other problem that might be causing issues is that "Gender" only has one value. Since the only value of "Gender" is "category" including it in the model might be causing the issues.